# Azure App Service times out after being idle, even when 'always on' is ticked

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service. Everything works fine, but from time-to-time it doesn't respond. That is, HTTP requests that a client makes time out. I can see this by looking at the analytics in the mobile app and in the App Service - the former sends a request, gets no response within 15 seconds, and times out. On the other side, the request isn't even logged by the service.

This happens whenever the service hasn't been used for a while (it's still in development so low traffic). This leads me to think that the service is somehow going to sleep, and then takes time to startup. If I follow that failed query with another query straight away, the second query is successful.

In App Service settings, there is a checkbox for 'always on'. I ticked this, but it made no difference to this particular problem.

Also, this is using the Standard, not Basic, tier.

Is there anything else one needs to do to get an Azure App Service not to stop responding like this?

Comment: Timeout will be caused by many issues. If you use cache in your web page and the cache is timeout, your web page need to reload this cache and spend lots of time. Have you tested it using multi different clients and check whether it is the issue from your client device.

Answer (score 2):

Long shot:

Is your site set up to be HTTPS only, using IIS Redirect?
If so, Always On won't work aa it doesn't support HTTPS. What happens is that IIS redirects to HTTPS without running your code.
You can set up an exception in your IIS Redirect rule to allow Always On to not use HTTPS.

However, the fact that you never see the request from the app in your log is very odd and indicates the problem might be something weirder.